# Where does RAILS_ROOT (Rails.root) come from?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I have a ruby on rails application that is located at `/home/user/application`. I have a Apache webserver whose DocumentRoot is `/var/www`. And I have a symlink `/var/www/application -> /home/user/application`.

My apache configuration section that concerns the ruby on rails is the following:

```
    RailsBaseURI /application
    <Directory /home/user/application>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
```

I modified the Passenger code so in the very beginning of it spawning it would print (to a file) the option `app_root`. If it matters, I modified the file `phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb` in the method `handle_spawn_application`.

The value that I get is `/home/user` and this is wrong, I needed `/home/user/application`. So my question is, how does Passenger figures out the `option['app_root']` (which becomes `RAILS_ROOT`|`Rails.Root`)?

Observation: I modified the Passenger code to hardcode `app_root` to `/home/user/application` and everything worked fine.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruby neither Ruby on Rails. If any useful information is missing please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the symlink so that /var/www/application points to /home/user/application/public

Then just change RailsBaseURI to RackBaseURI  and undo your changes to spawn_manager.rb

---

Previous discussion assumed single application.

```
    <Directory /var/www/application/public>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
```

See the [Apache Phusion documentation.](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2)
You need to add DocumentRoot and append /public to your Directory config and undo your changes to spawn_manager.rb.

As you noticed, the app_root is one directory up from what is specified..  The parent directory of /home/user/application/public is /home/user/application which is the Rails root.

You want RackBaseURI instead of RailsBaseURI for Rails > 3

The reasoning behind this is so that Apache serves the static assets (which are in the public directory) and then if that isn't present Passenger routes the request to the Rails app.

Comment: I can not set DocumentRoot to /var/www/application/public. What about my other sites?

Comment: You didn't mention other sites, read the next section of the doc.    I'll update the answer.

Comment: Dont worry. Your answer was enough for me to figure out my way around.